# C++ - Implementing quicksort using unsigned integers only?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I have

```
std::vector<unsigned int> numbers;
```

thats filled with numbers and needs to be quickSorted without using int index - only unsigned int is allowed as vector index.

All the quickSort examples that I've seen break when I convert all "int" to "unsigned int" 
because of index may be -1 in some cases (due to j--).

edit: Here is one example

```
void quickSort(std::vector<unsigned int> &numbers, unsigned int left, unsigned int right) {
        unsigned int i = left, j = right;
        unsigned int tmp;
        unsigned int pivot = numbers.size()/2;

        /* partition */
        while (i <= j) {
              while (numbers[i] < pivot)
                    i++;
              while (numbers[j] > pivot)
                    j--;
              if (i <= j) {
                    tmp = numbers[i];
                    numbers[i] = numbers[j];
                    numbers[j] = tmp;
                    i++;
                    j--;
              }
        };

        /* recursion */
        if (left < j)
              quickSort(numbers, left, j);
        if (i < right)
              quickSort(numbers, i, right);
  }
```

Modified version of: http://diogopinho.hubpages.com/hub/easy-quicksort-with-examples

Example above Segfaults because if j is unsigned int and becomes 0, j-- becomes a huge number (0xffffffff) and (i<=j) is always true. 
Does anyone know how to implement quickSort using unsigned int index only?

Comment: If you see where the error is coming from, you should be able to fix the problem yourself. It's hard to take a guess at your code without seeing it.

Comment: here's how I would do it: 1. get yourself a C++ stdlib implementation where `std::sort` is implemented as a quicksort; 2. `std::sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());`

Comment: What's a 0-1 situation? Show the specific code that you can't work out how to replace. I don't immediately see why a QuickSort implementation would use negative numbers anywhere.

Comment: @SteveJessop I agree, but even if it did, `0U - 1U` is still equal to `(unsigned int)( -1 )`.

Comment: There is zero reason `quicksort()` would *require* signed values. If you haven't found any, then you (a) haven't looked hard enough, and (b) never tried it yourself. So show how *you* did it and how it wasn't possible to used `unsigned` s. exclusively. And besides, given a `std::vector<>` and not being allowed to use `std::sort<>` I would implement it with iterators in the first place.

Comment: There should be no need to subtract values (assuming that's what you mean by "0-1 situations"); just compare them with `<`, which is well defined for `unsigned int`.

Comment: And if your reference code compares `int` by subtracting them then it's doing it wrong, because behavior of signed arithmetic is undefined on overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the page you linked to containing the description of the pivot, it is incorrectly implemented. That can cause the pivot not to be found and j becoming less than 0. If the pivot is correctly chosen as a number which is included in the range, I think this algorithm will work too with unsigned integers.

Answer (score 0):

This post is very old, but in case someone is still in the need, he can find an implementation which can tolerate unsigned int index [here](https://appdividend.com/2019/05/02/quick-sort-in-c-tutorial-with-example-c-quick-sort-program/)

```
int partition(int *a,int start,int end)
{
    int pivot=a[end];
    //P-index indicates the pivot value index

    int P_index=start;
    int i,t; //t is temporary variable

    //Here we will check if array value is 
    //less than pivot
    //then we will place it at left side
    //by swapping 

    for(i=start;i<end;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]<=pivot)
        {
            t=a[i];
            a[i]=a[P_index];
            a[P_index]=t;
            P_index++;
        }
     }
     //Now exchanging value of
     //pivot and P-index
      t=a[end];
      a[end]=a[P_index];
      a[P_index]=t;

     //at last returning the pivot value index
     return P_index;
 }
 void Quicksort(int *a,int start,int end)
 {
    if(start<end)
    {
         int P_index=partition(a,start,end);
             Quicksort(a,start,P_index-1);
             Quicksort(a,P_index+1,end);
    }
}
```